# TimeoutError when using python to send email

Tags: python, email, smtp, connection-timeout

I'm trying to write a python script to send an email. And here is the code:

```
def main():


    import smtplib
    import email.mime.text
    import email.mime.application
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

    from_email = 'xxx@gmail.com'
    from_email_pwd = '123456'
    to_email = 'yyy@gmail.com'

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = 'Subject'
    msg['From'] = from_email
    msg['To'] = to_email

    body = email.mime.text.MIMEText("Body")
    msg.attach(body)

    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
    s.starttls()
    s.login(from_email, from_email_pwd)
    s.sendmail(from_email, to_email, msg.as_string())
    s.quit()

    return

main()
```

While I can successfully run this code on my personal laptop, I came across problems when I try to run it on the company's desktop (working on PyCharm IDE with interpreter Python 3.5.1). Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PATH/stack.py", line 29, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/PATH/stack.py", line 21, in main
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
  File "C:\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 335, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 306, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "C:\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socket.py", line 711, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socket.py", line 702, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any thoughts what's going on?

Comment: Might be a firewall/port issue if it works at home but not at work :) maybe specify the port when creating your smtp instance?

Comment: I have tried several ports (587, 25 etc) but none of them work. So any suggestion about the firewall/port setting to make it work?